# Meteor 1.4 - React data loading techniques best practice

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am using Meteor 1.4 / React to build a medium sized app. so I am trying to find the 'best practice' for data handling between Meteor 1.4 / React to follow when building my app.

At the moment I am using createContainer to handle data between Meteor and React components as shown in the example below.

Having said that, I've read in many articles / forum posts about using Meteor packages / features like React Komposer, TrackerReact, and React Document container.

So I am not sure which of them is best to follow for a medium sized project that will by time increase in size. So I was wondering if someone passed with similar experience / tried those packages can share with me their experience?

Thanks in advance for your help and time

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

  export default class DDOrganization extends Component {

      getOrganizations(){
        let org = this.props.org;
        return Organizations.find({'name': {'$regex': org}});
      }

      renderOrganizations(){
        return this.getOrganizations().bind(this).map((org) => {
          return (
            <li key={org._id}><a href="#" data-id={org._id} onClick={this.props.setOrgState}>{org.name}</a></li>
          )
        });
      }

      render(){
          let {organizations} = this.props;
          return (
              <ul className="select-organization-list">
                  {this.renderOrganizations().bind(this)}
              </ul>
          )
      }

  };


  export default createContainer(() => {

      let organizations = {};
      let {org} = this.props;
      let orgSub = Meteor.subscribe("OrgSubscription", org);

      if(orgSub.ready()){
          organizations = Organizations.find({'name': {'$regex': org}}).fetch();
      }

      return {
          organizations: organizations
      }

  }, DDOrganization);
```

Comment: If I were you I would avoid using `createContainer`. There's a big [problem in it's implementation](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/devel/packages/react-meteor-data/ReactMeteorData.jsx#L102), which causes all wrapped subscription to be reevaluated if your computation gets invalidated by some reactive data source. This is wrong, because when your subscription parameters do not change the data coming from that subscription should stay intact.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so do you mind telling me what would you recommend as an alternative to createContainer for a medium sized Meteor 1.4 project? Having said that, I am sorry I didn't get this clearly here, so would you mind elaborate please? Based on what I understood so far, you're saying is that it will reevaluate all subscriptions in the container even those who didn't have their data changed on server, did I get this correct? Thanks

Comment: In short, I suggest using `react-komposer`. I will write more a little bit later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing things the same way that you are currently doing them for a pretty large project in production and it seems to work pretty well. I believe it is the recommended method by MDG.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, do you mind sharing how do you handle state (State management) in your React components under Meteor 1.4? Thanks

Comment: Sure, sorry it took so long. I use createContainer alongside the SubsManager package. Example:

    `export default CustomContainerData =  createContainer(() => {
      subsManager1.subscribe('sub1');
      subsManager2.subscribe('sub2');
      ... 
      return {
        loading: !(subsManager1.ready() && subsManager2.ready() && ...),
      };
    }, ReactClassName);`

The constructor could then handle any additional state elements like:
    `constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          statea: 0,
          stateb: [],
        };
    }`

Comment: And because there is a limit on comment length I had to add this comment as well to finish my examples. You could access/set the state like so:

`unfoldOpportunity(campaignId) {
    if (this.state.statea === campaignId) {
      this.setState({ statea: 0 });
    } else {
      this.setState({ statea: campaignId });
    }
  }`

I will admit that it can get tricky to manage complicated UI's but I generally need to refactor the UI into separate components when it gets to that point.